# I am getting a #Ref error while applying arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D)=0,,IF(AND(D2:D<65,M2:M="NO",N2:N="NO"),"Good Stock","")))
```

These are the respective columns

[image]

[image]

How can i rectify this error

Answer (score 0):

Within arrayformula function use `*` in the place of `and`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D)=0,,IF((D2:D<65)*(M2:M="NO")*(N2:N="NO"),"Good Stock","")))
```

- also you should just paste the formula in `Cell O2` and its automatically applied from `O2` and downwards. you should not be dragging the formula across `O2, O3, O4` and so on & that's what is most likely causing the `#REF!` error